# Bash script parameters

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line-interface

I need to write a **bash script**, and would like it to parse **unordered parameters** of the format:

```
scriptname --param1 <string> --param2 <string> --param3 <date>
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this, or am I pretty much stuck with $1, $2, $3?

*edit*

(note - I don't need long parameter names - single letters would be fine too)

Comment: why did you post the same thing on stackoverflow and here? This is more programming related anyway.

Comment: That is exactly why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt).

Comment: Thanks - That put me on the right track - I think that I actually want getopts - as it is apparently simpler, and I don't need the long names

Comment: Cool, but you need to fix your question then :) It specifically lists long param names in the example.